Journalctl throws error when using --follow argument
I have a systemd-journal-remote.service running that receives log messages from multiple hosts. The set-up works and journal entries are stored into one log file with this configuration:
# /etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf
# all server logs should go into one file
[Remote]
SplitMode=none

The systemd-journal-remote.service is updated with these additional configurations via a drop-in:
# /etc/systemd/system/systemd-journal-remote.service.d/10-update-http-in-execstart.conf
[Service]
# changed from https to http
# ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --listen-https=-3 --output=/var/log-server/journal/remote/
# empty default value before overriding it. Otherwise a systemd exception is raised: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --listen-http=-3 --output=/var/log/journal/remote/log.journal

[Install]
Also=systemd-journal-remote.socket

This journalctl command works fine: journalctl --quiet --reverse --file='log.journal' --unit 'my.service' The desired list of entries is returned. Whenever I want to follow the service's output by adding the --follow argument, I receive that error message:

"I Failed to get journal fd: Destination address required"

Can anyone point me into the right direction?
Installed systemd version: systemd 255 (255.4-1ubuntu8.1)

I found the problem. It seams that the path to the journal file MUST be absolute. Even when you run the command from the dir where the log file is stored.
This is the working solution:
journalctl --quiet --reverse --file='/var/log/journal/remote/log.journal' --unit 'my.service'

The same using a relativ path does not work:
cd /var/log/journal/remote/
journalctl --quiet --reverse --file='./log.journal' --unit 'my.service'

Quite interestingly: When you run the command on a file that is not found, normally it produces this error:
journalctl --file='/var/log/journal/remote/log.journalasdf' --follow  
Failed to open files: No such file or directory

The error "I Failed to get journal fd: Destination address required" is misleading.
